# Convert Epoch Time to Human Readable time

Tags: javascript, date, time, epoch

Does anyone know if there is a javascript ONLY way to convert an epoch number into a human readable date?  I have this code, but I keep getting back a number.  I want to convert this number into a human readable date if possible (ex: 2012/3/23).

This was a resource I used for my code... http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/

Play with my jsfiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/4FSEp/

```
var myDate=new Date();

myDate = myDate.setFullYear(2012,3,23);

document.write(myDate);

document.write(myDate.toGMTString()+"<br>"+myDate.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
myDate = myDate.setFullYear(2012, 3, 23);
```

to

```
myDate.setFullYear(2012, 2, 23);
```

(*edit* — wow I didn't know `setFullYear()` could also take a month and a day-of-month :-)

Those routines modify the date object, so there's no need to re-assign.

*edit* — if you have a date, and you want to move it to five days ahead of that date, you'd do this:

```
myDate.setDate( myDate.getDate() + 5 );
```

Comment: Not only "there's no need", you *should not* reassign (`setFullYear` returns an `int`).

Comment: @bfavaretto yes that's sort-of what I meant.  I'm looking around for some spec about the return value; the MDN page doesn't say.

Comment: Say I wanted to add five days to myDate..how would I do that??

Comment: @StacEver just add 5 to the third value - JavaScript Date objects automatically fix nonsense dates. Thus, if you tell it you want "April 33" it automatically makes that "May 3".

Comment: Also note that months are numbered 0 through 11, not 1 through 12.

Comment: what would the code look like for that Pointy...I deleted what you originally showed where each was broken up??

Comment: @Pointy It's strange that neither MDN or MSDN mentions the return value. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setFullYear.asp) do, but I don't trust them. But that seems to be in accordance to what's in [ECMA5 section 15.9.5.40](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.40).

Comment: @bfavaretto yes the spec definitely mentions it.

Comment: Sorry to bother again Pointy, say I want JUST the date and not the time...Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Well JavaScript doesn't provide much flexibility with date formats, but you can use `.getFullYear()`, `.getMonth()`, and `.getDate()` to get the numeric values, and then build the date string yourself. Don't forget: the month value returned will be a number from 0 to 11, so you'll want to add 1 to it before creating your date string. There's a library called [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com) that's handy, if you want more functionality.